# remove particle system from an object

Tags: particles

Scene: Default cube with default particle system

Running `bpy.data.particles.remove(bpy.data.particles['ParticleSettings'])` deletes the cube, however I need to remove only the particle system from the cube, leaving the cube in place. Going the `.ops` way is too slow on multiple objects.
What would be the best way to: 
A) delete a particle system from selected object?
B) delete **all** particle systems from **all** selected objects?

Comment: With o as the object, have you tried: o.modifiers.remove(o.modifiers[0]) where o.modifiers[0] corresponds to the particle system?